# Value Error eps=0.100000 as I try to reduce data dimensionaity. What could be the reason for this?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to use scikit's [GaussianRandomProjection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.random_projection.GaussianRandomProjection.html#sklearn.random_projection.GaussianRandomProjection) with my dataset which has a shape of `1599 x 11` as follows:

```
transformer = random_projection.GaussianRandomProjection()
X_new = transformer.fit_transform(wine_data.values[:, :11])
```

As I do this, I get an error that says:

```
ValueError: eps=0.100000 and n_samples=1599 lead to a
target dimension of 6323 which is larger than the original 
space with n_features=1
```

I do not understand the error. What exactly does it mean? How could I use `GaussianRandomProjection` to reduce data dimensionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a direct quotation from the official Scikit-Learn Doc on `GaussianRandomProjection` in its parameter `n_components`:

> Dimensionality of the target projection space.
>
> n_components can be automatically adjusted according to the number of
>   samples in the dataset and the bound given by the
>   Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma. In that case the quality of the embedding
>   is controlled by the eps parameter.
>
> **It should be noted that Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma can yield very
>   conservative estimated of the required number of components as it
>   makes no assumption on the structure of the dataset.**

It seems that in your case the estimator tends to yield a 6323-dimensional projected target after *"reducing"* the dimensionality. This is obviously unexpected, because you desired to reduce the dimension other than increasing it. I suggest that you first presume the dimension (i.e. 8) of your desired output and then test if the model works in an expected way.

```
transformer = GaussianRandomProjection(n_components=8) #Set your desired dimension of the output
X_new = transformer.fit_transform(wine_data.values[:, :11])
```

Good luck

Comment: Why it is not auto reducing the dimensionality?

Comment: @SuhailGupta Yes it is auto but **NOT** reducing! Because the estimated required number of components was considered of 6323 in your particular case. But you only have 11 features! Consequently, either you need to explicitly tell the algorithm how many components you want to be left or you can increase your `eps`. I prefer the former approach since it's more reliable.

Comment: @SuhailGupta BTW, if you want to dig deeper into how the `n_components` is automatically derived, please visit this [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.random_projection.johnson_lindenstrauss_min_dim.html). This `sklearn.random_projection.johnson_lindenstrauss_min_dim` function is used for `n_components` calculation.